# Line breaks in XSLT formatted code documentation (xml)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

Our WinForms based application takes documentation files that were generated by Visual Studio (Xml documentation), performs some XSLT transformation and displays the result in a WebBrowser control inside our form.

Problem is, We cannot seem to get line breaks to be displayed, for example for  tags in the xml documentation.

For example:

```
        <member name="T:Genesys.AgentLoginData">
            <summary>
            This is some test summary <br />
            New line here
            </summary>
        </member>
```

When used with the XSL transformation, the summary text will be truncated into a single line.

For simplification, the transformation does this for selecting the summary text:

```
<xsl:template match="member" >
<xsl:value-of select="summary" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

How can we properly get new lines to be displayed in the WebBrowser control inside our application?

EDIT: Adding the contents of"View Source" from the WebBrowser control. 
What i'm after is a new line after "This is a method", and so on.
The browser simply displays that in a single line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Action Help</title><style type="text/css">
          p  {text-indent:200px;}
          li {text-indent:180px;}
          h1 {color:navy;}
          h2 {color:blueviolet}
          h4 {color:navy;}
        </style></head><body><H2 xmlns="">AgentLogin</H2><H1 xmlns=""></H1><h3 xmlns="">
            This is a method 
            And its parameter 
            Check this out
            name</P></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for `xml:space="preserve"` directive. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468566.aspx for a decent article on how to handle XSL and whitespace on the .net stack.

Although I just noticed that you're displaying the resulting transform in a web browser control, which may mean that your problems actually with the produced HTML. Try viewing source on what you're displaying in the control and add that to your question.

Looking at the updated comments, and making some guesses, I think your problem is that you're using xsl:value-of, which just gets the text of the node, instead of xsl:copy-of, which would get the text of the node, along with the `<br/>` elements. Try replacing this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="summary" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="summary/node()" />
```

Your other option would be to escape the `<br/>` so that it come through as text instead of a child node, and leave disable-output-escaping on.

Comment: Added the output in my original question.

Comment: Looks like the output XML doesn't correspond to the input XML. Do you have <br />s in the XML for all the linebreaks you want?

Comment: Reading up a bit on the difference between copy-of and value-of, this seems to be what i'm after.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to learn the difference between [`<xsl:value-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#value-of) and [`<xsl:copy-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#copy-of).**

`<xsl:value-of>` only copies to the output the *string value* of the specified in the `select` attribute expression. This *excludes* any elements (so `<br/>` is not present in the output).

On the other hand `` `<xsl:copy-of> `` copies to the result tree all nodes in the node-set specified in the `select` attribute.

**Therefore the solution is simple**:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:template match="member" >
  <xsl:value-of select="summary" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:template match="member" >
  <xsl:copy-of select="summary/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In your "replace with", did you mean copy-of ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your generating your original xml, you may need to use html entities for these tags to be properly preserved.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

try

```
    <member name="T:Genesys.AgentLoginData">
        <summary>
        This is some test summary &lt;br /&gt;
        New line here
        </summary>
    </member>
```

Comment: This would work, but it is just unreadable. These comments are generated from XML documentation (from VS). Nobody would write these himself, unless of course these would (somehow) be transformed by some other tool, which adds complexity to the process...

Comment: Right, I was simply trying to point toward the right direction.  I have encountered some errors like this with Perl's XML parser.  The exact options are - of course going to vary between the two, but this is the general path you want to go down.  HTML tags either need to be escaped, or you need to tell your parser to blindly grab all the text of element `<summary>` without interpreting sub-tags (`<br />`)